# Bind combobox in DataGrid template using DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

Can you tell me how to bind combo-box in WPF Datagrid Column and bind it using database. I have search so many artistic or blog here but could get proper help for it. So please guide me how to achieve that.

Comment: If you have tried it yourself, can you show what have you tried so far so that redundancy of effort is saved.

Comment: Look here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301678/Step-by-Step-WPF-Data-Binding-with-Comboboxes

Comment: hi sandysands,i want bind combobox in datagrid column

Comment: we can do this in asp.net using onrowdatabound event.i like to do same here so what to do in wpf

Comment: show the code what have you tried so far? and why use datatable? you can use list or observablecollection to bind combobx

Comment: want to use database value which is entered using another form